# Add Bogus Aggregate for Materialized View?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, materialized-views

In BigQuery, is it possible to create a bogus aggregate such that I can use a materialized view to query a table?

The query:

```
SELECT
  date_of_data,
  id,
  endpoint,
  value
FROM
  `project.dataset.table`
WHERE
  endpoint='some_endpoint'
```

If I try to make a materialized view out of that I get `Materialized Views must contain an aggregator`.

I want to use a materialized view because the historical data does not change and filtering by `endpoint` creates a much smaller table to query against later on.

Comment: Do you have `project.dataset.table` partitioned? Otherwise, every materialized view refresh will cause the full `project.dataset.table` scan - [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/materialized-views#partition_alignment)

Comment: Yes, it is partitioned by Day on date_of_data.

Comment: The materialized views now support without aggr: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/materialized-views#without_aggr

Answer (score 1):

Probably you can try any aggregate function and list all available columns in the `GROUP BY` statement:

```
SELECT
  date_of_data,
  id,
  endpoint,
  value,
  count(*) as cnt
FROM
  `project.dataset.table`
WHERE
  endpoint='some_endpoint'
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4
```